# Do I need PHP to serve an HTTP Header with the correct content-type for RSS/ATOM?

Tags: php, xml, http, rss, atom-feed

I want to send my RSS/Atom feeds with the correct Content-type header, can I do this without access to PHP or any other server-side language? The goal is for the browser to treat the file as a feed and not just a plain XML file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can tell the server to send that specific file with a specific media type.

Apache has the [`AddType`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype) and [`ForceType`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#forcetype) directive to do that:

```
# send all .atom files with application/atom+xml
AddType application/atom+xml .atom

# send only foo.bar as application/atom+xml
<FilesMatch ^foo\.bar$>
    ForceType application/atom+xml
</FilesMatch>
```

You can use [`<Directory>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory), [`<DirectoryMatch>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directorymatch), [`<Files>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#files), [`<FilesMatch>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#filesmatch), [`<Location>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location) and [`<LocationMatch>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#locationmatch) sections to restrict the directives only to specific directories, files or URL paths. But be aware of the [context](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Context) they are allowed in. Only `<Files>` and `<FilesMatch>` can be used in a .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

If your RSS/ATOM feed has a specific extension, or is served from a specific dorectory, I suppose you could use Apache's [AddType directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype), so Apache would serve your RSS feeds with the right content-type :

> The `AddType` directive maps the given
>   filename extensions onto the specified
>   content type. MIME-type is the MIME
>   type to use for filenames containing
>   extension.

Not tested, but I suppose something like this, either in your Apache's main configuration file, or in a `.htaccess` file, might do, for RSS feeds :

```
AddType application/rss+xml .rss
```

And, for ATOM, something like this, probably :

```
AddType application/atom+xml .atom
```